# Make simple calculations with C++ pre-processor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

In my C++ application I configure some features in this way:

```
#define LED_SIZE        113
#define SEGMENT_SIZE    3

const int LED_SEGMENTS[SEGMENT_SIZE] = {30, 70, 13};
```

I would like to check if the sum of the literal values are equal to `LED_SIZE`:

```
30+70+13 = 113
```

I'm interested to do this at **compile time**, using a pre-processor directives.
If the sum is not correct it should not compile.

Comment: You know you can do that at compile time without any preprocessor, right?

Comment: Perhaps you want [static_assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)

Comment: Study `constexpr`. If tou have `if` condition which is constant at compile time, compiler will optimize the test out. Is there a reason this is not good enough?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, no I don't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using a pre-processor directives

It is not possible to access arrays using preprocessor directives. `LED_SEGMENTS[0]` means literally `LED_SEGMENTS[0]` for preprocessor, there is no array access in preprocessor.

You could stay with it in preprocessor world, and then write a variadic overloaded argument macro to calculate the sum of the comma separated list:

```
#define LED_SIZE        113
#define SEGMENT_SIZE    3

#define LED_SEGMENTS    30, 70, 13

#define SUM_1(a)  a
#define SUM_2(a, ...)  a + SUM_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SUM_3(a, ...)  a + SUM_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SUM_4(a, ...)  a + SUM_3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SUM_N(_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...)  SUM##N
#define SUM_IN(...)  SUM_N(__VA_ARGS__,_4,_3,_2,_1)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define SUM(...)  SUM_IN(__VA_ARGS__)

#if SUM(LED_SEGMENTS) != LED_SIZE
#error "SUM(LED_SEGMENTS) != LED_SIZE"
#endif
```

> to do this at compile time

You should use:

```
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#define LED_SIZE        113
#define SEGMENT_SIZE    3

constexpr int LED_SEGMENTS[SEGMENT_SIZE] = {30, 70, 13};
static_assert(std::accumulate(std::begin(LED_SEGMENTS), std::end(LED_SEGMENTS), 0) == LED_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `static_assert`

```
#define LED_SIZE        113
#define SEGMENT_SIZE    3

constexpr int LED_SEGMENTS[SEGMENT_SIZE] = {30, 70, 13}; // this need to be constexpr

#include <numeric>

static_assert(
    std::accumulate(LED_SEGMENTS,LED_SEGMENTS+SEGMENT_SIZE,0) == LED_SIZE
);
```

note: `std::accumulate` is `constexpr` only since c++20, you may need to write a custom one for earlier standard.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the C pre-processor.

```
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
constexpr int LED_SIZE = 113;
constexpr int SEGMENT_SIZE = 3;
constexpr std::array<int, SEGMENT_SIZE> values{30, 70, 13};
static_assert(std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0) == LED_SIZE);
```